# How to get predicted classes from y_pred

Tags: python, json, keras, deep-learning, lstm

I have trained my model and saved it as json file and then i have saved the wights and load it as h5

Then i have used it in another script in order to feed some records to test the accuracy of the model what i want to do is:
Making the model say what is the predicted label and then i must compare it with the true label from the csv file but I don’t know how to get the predicted values?
I tried this
`predict_x= loaded_model(X_test) y_pred=np.argmax(predict_x,axis=1)`

And then
`for i in y_pred`
to loop through y_pred, i thought i could see my y classes which are from 0-4 while actually i found numers like 17,22,13…

Can in one till me what I should do?
Thank you in advance

………………………………………………….

Comment: Why are you using the ```np.argmax()``` function here? In order to get the maximum value from each row of predict_x, you should be using just the ```np.max()``` function with ```axis=1```. Since ```np.argmax()``` returns the position of the maximum value, you're getting values like 17,22,13 etc, instead of the actual maximum value.

Comment: i tried this too but i got values like 0.30474743
0.30446094
0.30464223 , and i don't want these i just want to get my classes values which are 0,1,2,3,4

Comment: Can you post more details about the ```X_test, predict_x```? What are their shapes and what kind of values they contain